# Capacity - VSTS - User Privledges

Tags: azure-devops

I want to set some *Scrum Master*s up with privileges to amend the **Capacity** of team members within a Sprint of a Project:

[image]

Which permissions are needed for a *basic* user to access this? I'm NOT using Azure AD, so just using the Web Portal to setup.

This is for the SaaS Visual Studio Team Services Online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options to grant permission to edit work item capacity for a certain user.

#### Option 1: Add the user as a member for the default team

You just need to add the user to the default team, then he/she can edot the work item capacity:

In project Security page (https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_admin/_security) -> select default team (such as `Git_Scrum Team` in below example) -> Members Tab -> Add -> add the user -> Save changes.

[image]

#### Option 2: Add the user as a member for the Project Administrators group

In project Security page -> select Project Administrators group -> Members Tab -> Add -> add the user -> Save changes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could set the user as a team administrator.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/add-team-administrator?view=vsts

Comment: Thanks for the reply, very much appreciated. Is that the only way? Giving the Scrummies full admin privs seems alittle overkill, but if that's the only way..so be it :D

Comment: Unfortunately you have to grand admi privs.